# angular CLI change build warnings to errors

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there any chance to configure `ng build` in a way that warnings change to errors?

This would be convenient for CI builds. I know this from other build tools, but haven't found any configuration parameters for that.

Comment: When you say convenient CI builds. where do you run the build ?. Why do you want to turn warnings into errors. Even if you want to do that that should be done at complier level. 

An error occurs when your source is not a legal program. Syntax and type errors are typical

A warning occurs when your program is legal, and the compiler can produce object code for it, but something doesn’t look right.

Comment: 1. You can check for code without warnings in a CI process, e.g. GitHub actions. It is a good idea to tackle warnings instead of just leaving them.
2. Is there a way to achieve this behavior with `ng build`?

Comment: Not sure, if we can set something on the ng build to stop at warnings. But if we know what types of warnings. We can use linters and with linters it should fail the build.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is still relevant, but for anyone stumbling across this question, it is possible to emit angular compiler warnings as errors.
Described in the documentation here:
https://angular.io/extended-diagnostics#configuration

So what you need to do is open you project's tsconfig.json file, and add the following:

```
{
 ...
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    ...
    "extendedDiagnostics": {
      "defaultCategory": "error"
    }
  }
}
```

This will cause any compilation warning to emit errors instead.

Comment: expand please https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Answer (score 0):

I also think that angular should provide an option to handle warnings as errors on build. If you don't prevent warnings from reaching the main branch, after a while they become more and more and new developers just ignore them.

Initially I thought it would be easy to find a workaround for that by just checking if the output of the command includes "Warning" but it has turned out to be much more difficult than expected. The problem is that by doing this, you change the status code and then the pipeline doesn't fail anymore on error, e.g. `npm run build |& tee -a =~ "Warning" && exit 64` solves the problem but also adds a new problem - it doesn't fail when `npm run build` has an error. And also you of course don't want to suppress an error message in case of an error.

So my final solution looks like this:

```
npm run build |& tee build.log;
result_code=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
if cat build.log | grep -q "Warning"; then 
   echo "Warning in build"
   exit 64
fi
exit $result_code
```